# SQL lookup and reference table definitions

Tags: sql, semantics, definitions

I need some clarification. What is a lookup table and what is a reference table in SQL?

I was under the impression that a lookup table is a table that has static data that hardly ever changes (e.g. a table that has all 50 states and their capitals) and a reference table is one that contains primary keys and links two other tables. In the example below, Table B would be a reference table. Can someone tell me what Table B is called?

```
Table A
CustomerID
CustomerName
CustomerAddress

Table B
CustomerID
OrderID

Table C
OrderID
OrderDate
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Table B is a **[Link Table or Junction Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_table)**.

Reference and Lookup tables can mean different things for different sources, and I am not aware of a strict definition to differentiate the two.

For me personally I normally use a **reference** to mean an long value stored out of the main table (like a `StoreID`), and **lookup** to mean a list of allowable values (enforced by a FK constraint) for a certain field.

Answer (score 4):

There is no hard-and-fast definition for those terms. It really comes down to whether or not the other person knows what you are talking about.

Among the people I work with table B would be called a "Mapping Table".

Answer (score 2):

- Fork table
- many-to-many relation table
- link table
- map table